# How can I put this php into this html?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So I have the following php:

```
    $latest_cpt = get_posts("post_type=event&numberposts=1"); 
$theidone =$latest_cpt[0]->ID;
$this_post_id =  $theidone; //get_the_ID();
$key_2_value =  get_post_meta( $this_post_id, 'custom_select', true );
if( ! empty( $key_2_value )) {
$thisisworking =   $key_2_value ;
 ;}
```

I need to put all the php code above  where `'.$thisisworking.'` is below. I keep getting semi colon is unexpected php errors when I try.

```
div id="indent">
 <span style="font-size:0.2em">
    <h2><?php echo $EM_Category->output('#_CATEGORYNAME'); ?></h2>
    </span>
    <?php echo $EM_Category->output('#_CATEGORYNOTES'); ?></p>
    <p> <?php //echo $EM_Category->output('#_CATEGORYALLEVENTS'); ?>  </p>


    <?php echo EM_Events::Output( array('format'=>
'
<li>
<br />
<span style="color: #ed834e; clear:both;  display:block"> '.$thisisworking.'#_EVENTNAME </span> 
 </li>
<br />
<b> 
<li>
```

Can someone tell me how this can be achieved?

`echo EM_Events::Output( array('format'=>` is how the wordpress plugin author, says templates to modify his wordpress plugin should be coded. Can anyone help please?

**UPDATE:** I tried this but it doesn't seem to make any difference:

```
function letsmakethiswork()  { 
    $latest_cpt = get_posts("post_type=event"); 
    foreach ( $latest_cpt as $cpt_post ) {
        $theidone =$cpt_post->ID;
        $this_post_id =  $theidone; //get_the_ID();
        $key_2_value =  get_post_meta( $this_post_id, 'custom_select', true );
        if( ! empty( $key_2_value )) {
            $thisisworking =   $key_2_value ;
        }
        return $key_2_value;
    }
}
    // END OF NEW CATEGORY SYSTEM 
?>

<div id="indent">
 <span style="font-size:0.2em">
    <h2><?php echo $EM_Category->output('#_CATEGORYNAME'); ?></h2>
    </span>
    <?php echo $EM_Category->output('#_CATEGORYNOTES'); ?></p>
    <p> <?php //echo $EM_Category->output('#_CATEGORYALLEVENTS'); ?>  </p>


    <?php echo EM_Events::Output( array('format'=>
'
<li>
<br />
<span style="color: #ed834e; clear:both;  display:block"> '.letsmakethiswork().'#_EVENTNAME </span> 
 </li>
<br />
<b> 
<li>
```

Comment: That last semi-colon looks suspect to me `;}` but then I don't do PHP

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn You would think that would cause an error, but it doesn't. You can have extra semicolons all over the place in PHP and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn See: https://eval.in/348210

Comment: @Mike Now that's just silly

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn I agree completely. PHP tends to be silly more often than not.

Comment: @mattnewbie You haven't even ended the last string or put the necessary closing brackets in at the end. How do you even expect this to work? Also, the error says exactly what line is producing the error. You need to put some effort into figuring it out.

Comment: @Mike               I have put hours of effort into trying to figure this out, I didn't post on this website at the first whim.  I have ended the last string & put the necessary closing brackets in, but I didn't think they would be beneficial to post here. Lesson learned.

Comment: @mattnewbie Can you indicate which line is the one producing the error?

Comment: @mike it's the `.letsmakethiswork().` that doesn't seem to be working. It only displays the value associated with the first post and does not display the values associated with  the following posts. There isn't a php error. This code is  from the updated code above. Thank-you for the support, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: `There isn't a php error` It would have been nice if you had mentioned this... You need to be as specific as you can in your questions or people can't help you. You said that your latest update "doesn't seem to make any difference". I would take that to mean that you are still getting the same PHP error as before.

Comment: The reason it's only displaying the first value is because in your loop you are doing `return`, so it will never be executed more than once.

Comment: You are going to need to work out your logic a bit better. I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but if you want to return a string containing multiple elements, you will have to concatenate them together and return the final string at the end, after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn it into a function?

```
function foo() { 
   ... your mangled code ...
   return $whatever_you_built;
}

$string = "foo bar " . foo() . " baz qux";
```